# Pushing cataloged objects to a project

Tags: watson-studio, watson-knowledge-catalog

My problem concerns pushing cataloged objects in Watson Knowledge Catalog to projects.  I find that it does not consistently push all of my selected catalog objects to the project. In my case, I have 4 objects I am trying to push to the project.  Usually what happens is that two of the four assets are successfully pushed the first time (a connection to a DB2 warehouse, and the corresponding Connected Data), with 2 other Data Assets failing.  If I retry the push with the 2 Data Assets, it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your scenario and pushed 4 connected assets (from Db2 Warehouse on Cloud) to a project, but was unable to reproduce what you're seeing.

Are all your objects from the same connection?

Did you get an error code when 2 of the data assets failed to be added to project?

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was not 4 connected assets from the same connection. I had 1 connected asset, 1 connection, and two assets that were from a file upload. The connection and the connected asset were pushed successfully. The other two assets failed the first time. Note, this was not just my account that failed. This exercise was part of a lab and all attendees had the same or similar issue. Note, I'm using a lite account.